# Spring Boot / Jetty + SSL: Keystore not found (FileNotFoundException)

Tags: java, spring-boot, ssl, keystore, embedded-jetty

I am trying to enable SSL with embedded jetty in a Spring Boot Application.

**Spring Boot Starter Version: 2.1.0.RELEASE**

**My configuration:**

I created a **keystore** with the following command:

```
keytool -genkey -keyalg RSA -alias webapp -keystore keystore.jks -storepass password -keysize 2048
```

The resulting keystore.jks file was placed in `src/main/resources/ssl`.

The tutorials mostly say that referencing this keystore in the **application.yaml** should be enough to "make it work":

```
server:
    port: 9292
    servlet:
        context-path: /
    ssl:
        key-store: classpath:keystore.jks
        key-store-password: password
        key-alias: webapp
        key-store-type: JKS
```

**Error:**

When I try to start the application, it fails:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Could not find key store 'classpath:keystore.jks'
at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.jetty.SslServerCustomizer.configureSslKeyStore(SslServerCustomizer.java:195) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.jetty.SslServerCustomizer.configureSsl(SslServerCustomizer.java:164) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.jetty.SslServerCustomizer.customize(SslServerCustomizer.java:73) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.jetty.JettyServletWebServerFactory.customizeSsl(JettyServletWebServerFactory.java:195) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.jetty.JettyServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(JettyServletWebServerFactory.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:179) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:152) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
... 13 common frames omitted
    Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [keystore.jks] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
at org.springframework.util.ResourceUtils.getURL(ResourceUtils.java:137) ~[spring-core-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.jetty.SslServerCustomizer.configureSslKeyStore(SslServerCustomizer.java:190) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
... 19 common frames omitted
```

When I look into the maven target directory though, the keystore.jks is placed under classes/ssl, so it should be in the classpath, right?

Can someone point out what I am missing?

**Edit:**

Strangely enough, moving the keystore.jks to `src/main/resources` seems to fix the problem. Why jetty able to find the keystore there, but not in the subdirectory `src/main/resources/ssl`?

Comment: did you tried `java -jar $JETTY_HOME/start.jar --list-classpath` to get classpathes

Comment: I have run in to this problem before and seems like a bad implementation. Instead of passing a classpath you could try file:keystore.jks but even that would not work. 
You can debug in to it and see! Best option as you mentioned it is saving it in resources folder. Spent quite a lot of time on this at the end went on saving it in resources. Btw this is not a Jetty issue had the same problem with tomcat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classpath by default is set tot `src/main/resources`. Meaning if you have `subdirectories` inside you need to specify the full path to your `jks file`:

**`key-store: classpath:ssl/keystore.jks`**